# Answers left unvoted/unaccepted

Tags: support, comments, new-users, accepted-answer

My question is related to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers). However, for me, it is not about wanting my answer to be accepted. As a fairly new user in the stack exchange community, it would be very helpful to get feedback/verification if my answers were good or not. Of course, feedback is in the form of votes and comments or acceptance. I know I should just not worry (and have patience) about my answers being left unnoticed for a long time or not getting seen at all. As I answered a couple of questions over the days without getting any feedback I am slightly concerned my input might not have been sufficient enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE wide, feedback is primarily provided via the voting system; if your posts are below our standards, you'll know soon enough (downvotes). If they are outstanding, you'll notice through upvotes. Comments are usually placed to clarify stuff.

Two out of your three answers here received a total of 3 upvotes and no downvotes. That should tell you something, namely that your answers are OK, but they didn't receive much attention. The best way to get a sense of community standards is by participating, i.e., asking questions and posting answers.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes people comment on answers, either to explain why they are down-voting them or to suggest an improvement. However, there is a certain reluctance to do this as it can be met with an abusive response.

I don’t believe I have encountered any of your contributions, and that raises another factor — the number of people in certain specialities may be quite small.